# Rails 3 NameError Uninitialized Constant EventsController::Events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, controller

Ok so I made a model, controller, and some views for an 'Event' (didn't use scaffolding).

Anyways when going to the events route I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant EventsController::Events
app/controllers/events_controller.rb:4:in `index'
```

This is my events controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @events = Events.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @events }
    end
  end
end
```

Any thoughts on why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `Event.all`, not `Events.all`. (When calling your model class directly, always use the singular form)

Comment: Yep that did it. Thank you :) I'll accept as soon as stack overflow lets me (~8 min)